# Trying to create a hamburger menu with javascript but the code is not running

Tags: javascript, hamburger-menu

Following a youtube tutorial on making a hamburger menu but for some reason my js code isn't working..

```
const menuIcon = document.querySelector
('.hambuger-menu');
const navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');

menuIcon.addEventListener ('click', () => {
  navbar.classList.toggle('change');
});
```

is there anything wrong with it? I'm using Atom

Comment: If you run this in the chrome dev console of the webpage (the one with a navbar class and a hambuger-menu class, what errors do you see?

Comment: Also, maybe 'hambuger-menu' should be 'hamburger-menu'?